# Why is Dspace still using the old version of a .jar I updated?

Tags: dspace

I made the localization for the classes ReportGenerator and HTMLReport, which can be found in the dspace-api.jar, so my html reports would be generated in my language, but it's still being generated in english, is there anything else I need to do? 
ps. I did generate a new jar, replaced the older one for the new localized version, restarted the tomcat and translated the dstat.map too.

Comment: I forgot to say but these two are localized in [..]/lib/dspace-api.jar/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical DSpace installation, there are multiple copies of the dspace-api jar file.  If I run the following from the [dspace-install] directory, you will see the following:

```
find webapps lib -name dspace-api*.jar
webapps/oai/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/oai/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
webapps/rdf/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/rdf/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
webapps/swordv2/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/swordv2/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
webapps/sword/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/sword/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
webapps/xmlui/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/xmlui/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar
webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar 
lib/dspace-api-lang-5.0.7.jar
```

Have you made your changes in the [dspace-src] directory and then run the maven and ant build processes?  That would ensure that your changes make it into all of the correct jar files.

Comment: The only thing I did was replace the dspace-src/lib/dspace-api-5.8.jar and restart my Tomcat, should i do the same to the rest of the .jars? I'm not sure if I have access to anything else or how to do it because I only have remote access through PuTTy and WinSCP.
Thnx for the answer

Comment: If you want a sustainable solution, you will need to make the changes in [dspace-src] and then run the maven and ant build tasks.  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-InstallationInstructions  If you get stuck, reach out to one of the DSpace support channels: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Support

Comment: Thnx, I will try to find the right directory, it seems mine is different from the one in the URL and I wasn't the one who did the installation.

Comment: It might seem stupid but the only thing I had to do was reboot the server, since it was a server that I didn't have full control over it, I couldn't do that without asking for permission to do so, and only after a certain problem occurred that demanded me to reboot was I able to learn that was what I had to do. Thanks for the help